# SQL Server Login Access getting revoked by a daily database refresh

Tags: sql-server, permissions

Scenario : I have granted dbdatareader access on a database to the dev team. They do have daily database refresh in place . Because of this the permissions to the login , which is a SQL login are getting revoked daily because of this database refresh job.

Since Dev team cannot add a block to add permissions automatically after the database refresh , how should I as sysadmin deal this case . I get tickets daily to grant read-only access for that database. I cannot grant them dbaccessadmin due to security issues.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you edit the database image (that which is restored) to add a `CONTAINED USER`? ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver15 ) - that will fix the issue in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try creating a SQL Agent job that runs once an hour and checks if the permission is present. If not, add the permission back. With it being a dev region, I wouldn't be super worried about this approach.

Something like...

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = '<dev_user>')
    CREATE USER [<dev_user>] FROM LOGIN <dev_user>

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER <dev_user>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Correct Query for above solution

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.database_principals WHERE [name] = '<dev_user>')

CREATE USER [<dev_user>] FROM LOGIN "<dev_user>"

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER "<dev_user>"

Comment: How is this different to the existing answer?